# Install a driver to Windows 7 bypassing the "incompatible" message

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is there any way to install an INF driver to Windows 7, ignoring the "this driver is incompatible with this system" message? I am trying to prepare to image a copy of Windows 7 from a virtual machine to a real one and need to put the USB 3 drivers on so I can use the mouse/keyboard once the image is copied over.

EDIT: it's a Windows 7 driver from Intel for the NUC5PPYH. I think the issue currently lies in that the device isn't there, which it won't be until I image it onto the NUC. But if I image it onto the NUC without the drivers, I loose USB support, and without USB support, I can't use my mouse or keyboard to install the other drivers.

Comment: If a driver is being reported as being incompatible, then its likely won't work, even if you were to bypass this warning message.  There are lots of Windows 7 USB 3 drivers you can slipstream why use one that isn't compatible?

Comment: @Ramhound this one is definitely compatible. In fact, I'm using it on the NUC right now. And the reason I would like to use this one is because this is direct from Intel's website.